# OPEN XML SDK Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, openxml-sdk

I have written some code based on some tutorials to update an existing word document with data from my database tables.

I keep getting the program crashing and advising that I may have an infinite loop, however I am using a for each statement and when I debug it tells me i only have one record.  Cannot understand where the problem is.

If someone can assist that would be greatly appreciated.  Code below

Controller

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;
using Mojito.Models;


namespace Mojito.Controllers
{
    public class KronosDesignDocumentController : Controller
    {
        private MojitoContext _db = new MojitoContext();
        //
        // GET: /KronosDesignDocument/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(_db.Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName");
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Load(int customerId)
        {
            var kronosDesignTemplate = new KronosDesignDocument.CreateDesignDoc(@"C:\Users\Craig Cocker\Documents\XML Files\Test_Design_Template.docx");

            kronosDesignTemplate.CustomerDesignDocument();

            ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(_db.Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.Message = "Configuration has been loaded successfully";
            return View("Index");
        }


    }
}
```

Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.Linq;


namespace Mojito.Models
{
    public class KronosDesignDocument
    {
        public static MojitoContext _db = new MojitoContext();

        public class CreateDesignDoc
        {
            private readonly string _xmlPath;
            //private readonly int _customerId;

            public CreateDesignDoc(string pathToXmlFiles)
            {
                _xmlPath = pathToXmlFiles;
            }

            public IEnumerable<Customer> CustomerDesignDocument()
            {

                WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_xmlPath, true);

                var docPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                var doc = docPart.Document;
                var table = new Table();

                var tb = new TopBorder();
                tb.Val = BorderValues.DashDotStroked;
                tb.Size = 12;

                var borders = new TableBorders();
                borders.TopBorder = tb;

                borders.LeftBorder = new LeftBorder() {Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 12};
                borders.RightBorder = new RightBorder() {Val = BorderValues.Single};
                borders.BottomBorder = new BottomBorder() {Val = BorderValues.Single};
                borders.InsideHorizontalBorder = new InsideHorizontalBorder() {Val = BorderValues.Single};
                borders.InsideVerticalBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder() {Val = BorderValues.Single};

                var props = new TableProperties();
                props.Append(borders);

                table.Append(props);

                var customers = _db.Customers.ToList();
                var customerCollection = new List<Customer>();


                foreach (var c in customers)
                {
                    var tr = new TableRow();
                    var customerName = c.CustomerName;

                    var tc = new TableCell();

                    var runProp = new RunProperties();
                    runProp.Append(new Bold());
                    runProp.Append(new Color() {Val = "FF0000"});

                    var run = new Run();
                    run.Append(runProp);

                    var t = new Text(customerName);
                    run.Append(t);

                    var justification = new Justification();
                    justification.Val = JustificationValues.Center;
                    var paraProps = new ParagraphProperties(justification);

                    var p = new Paragraph();
                    p.Append(paraProps);
                    p.Append(run);
                    tc.Append(p);

                    var tcp = new TableCellProperties();
                    var tcw = new TableCellWidth();
                    tcw.Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa;
                    tcw.Width = "2000";
                    tcp.Append(tcw);
                    tcp.Append(tcp);
                    tr.Append(tc);
                    table.Append(tr);
                }
                doc.Body.Append(table);
                doc.Save();
                return customerCollection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Mojito.Models.KronosDesignDocument


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kronos Design Document";
}

<h1>Load Kronos Data</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Load", "KronosDesignDocument", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Customer.cshtml")</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <input type="submit" value="Create Design Document" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Add what line does it crash and what is the exact exception (inner exception if available) you get?

Comment: System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll   It appears to get back to the controller, returns the view and then just crashes.  the troubleshooting tips say make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.  It does not give me an option to look at the inner exception

Comment: Is this line `tcp.Append(tcp);` correct? It appends a reference to it self. That might cause a stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much - I have been looking for that for hours.  Sometimes you cannot see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method to create your document you have this line:

```
tcp.Append(tcp);
```

that basically appends a reference to its self. I assume the OpenXML stuff expects you to take care of peventing such self-references and if you don't it's only way it has left is break with an StackOverflow exception.

If you fix that line, to

```
tc.Append(tcp);
```

all is good...